# xpath или css поиск по условию "ИЛИ"

Tags: css, xpath

Пишу локатор, необходимо чтобы он искал значение по условию, т.е одно условие или другое.  К примеру Test5 или Test4. На данный момент у меня есть такой

`css input[id*='_DATE']`

Под поиск попадают все ID-ники которые заканчиваются на `"_DATE"`
А мне же надо чтобы попадали только те которые содержать название ID-ка 
`Test5_DATE` или `Test4_DATE`, а все остальные заканчивающие на `_DATE`отбрасывались.

Comment: `[id*="test5_date"] , [id*="test4_date"]`

Comment: Спасибо, работает